# DateTime displaying differently on Web server and local machine for same code (WebFroms)

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I'm currently seeing a small discrepancy between an ASP.NET WebForms application on my local machine and on a server that I'm deploying to.

I am retrieving a date from a database (the actual db is the same in both cases). The date is the 1st of January 1900.

In my local machine this is displayed inside a text box as "01/01/1900"

However on the server it is displayed as "1/1/1900"

the code for assigning the date to the control is:

```
txtEffectiveDate.Text = ((DateTime)temp.Rows[0]["effective_date"]).ToShortDateString();
```

where temp is a DataTable representing the output of a stored procedure.

I have built the solution and transferred the relevant .dll file onto the server so it should the same code in both cases. I have also copied over the relevant .aspx page just to be sure but again that doesnt' make a difference.

Is there some kind of setting on the server that I need to tweak so that it shows the dates the same was as my local machine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[ToShortDateString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.datetime.toshortdatestring%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) formats your date according to the pattern defined by the  [DateTimeFormatInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.aspx).ShortDatePattern and its default value is controlled by the voice International settings in control panel.

Probably on your work machine is set as `dd/MM/yyyy` while on your server is `d/M/yyyy`

If you want to keep your working machine your could change to

```
txtEffectiveDate.Text = ((DateTime)temp.Rows[0]["effective_date"]).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

Or, just to follow the formal route, (see the MSDN examples in ToShortDateString)

```
CultureInfo originalCulture = new CultureInfo(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name);
originalCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern = "d/M/yyyy";
txtEffectiveDate.Text = ((DateTime)temp.Rows[0]["effective_date"])
                        .ToString(originalCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern));
```